# D flipflop in keypad

Tags: flipflop

Why D flipflop is used in keypad for LCD ( U2 in schematic shown below ).

[image: Small view]

[image: Zoomed view]

Is it for buffer? unidirectional or bidirectional?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's for buffer or latch, unidirectional.